# nHibernate aggregate query

Tags: nhibernate, projection, queryover

I'm attempting to put the following SQL query into an nHiberate QueryOver statement and I'm failing miserably.

```
Select top 15 percent
    People.personId
,People.Name
    ,SUM(Marks.Score)
from 
    People
    inner join [sessions] on [sessions].PersonId = People.PersonId
    inner join Marks on Marks.SessionId = [Sessions].SessionId
group by
    People.Name
    ,People.PersonId
order by
    SUM(Marks.Score) asc
```

My objects are:

- Person
- Session
- Mark

With the obvious FK constraints (people --> Session --> Marks).

Might someone give me some advice?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

joins are easy enough with `.Join()`. If you've defined those relations in your mappings, then you don't even have to specify how the join is made.
I usually find it more convenient to use `JoinAlias`.
Aggregations are done using `Projections` (see aliases and projections [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)).

You'll need a simple sum projection, and a grouping projection, of course.

For the result, you can either use an `object []` and cast it (as in the link above), or you can define a custom DTO, and use `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`. ([here](http://ayende.com/blog/2706/nhibernate-for-sql) is a pretty old blog post; the syntax has now changed to allow for lambda expressions).

Concerning top 15 percent- I'm not sure.
`QueryOver().Take()` allows for a constant; not sure there's native support for percentages.
You could implement your own projection, though. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257585/nhibernate-querover-with-paging-while-selecting-top-1-of-subquery).

**Edit: a simple projection example**
How lazy can I be? I just copied this from [github](https://gist.github.com/939649).
It has joins, aliases, projections.. everything you need. I added a SUM projection just for fun.
Notice how all the other properties have to be grouped-by, of course:

```
Customer customer = null;
    Employee employee = null;
    OrderHeader orderHeader = null;

    var orderHeaders = Session.QueryOver<Order>()
        .JoinAlias(o => o.Customer, () => customer)
        .JoinAlias(o => o.Employee, () => employee)
        .SelectList(list => list
            .SelectGroup(o => o.OrderedOn).WithAlias(() => orderHeader.OrderedOn)
            .SelectGroup(o => customer.Name).WithAlias(() => orderHeader.Name)
            .SelectGroup(o => employee.FirstName).WithAlias(() => orderHeader.FirstName)
            .SelectGroup(o => employee.LastName).WithAlias(() => orderHeader.LastName)
            .SelectSum(o => employee.Salary).WithAlias(() => orderHeader.JhonnysProjectionExample))
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<OrderHeader>())
        .List<OrderHeader>();
```

Comment: Any change of an example?  Just of the aggregation.  Pretty please :-)

Answer (score 0):

`TOP n PERCENT` is a nonstandard SQL construct (a very useful one, I might add)

There's no support for that in any NH query method. Just keep it as SQL.